# How to build a subgraph from transitive edges?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a graph with reified relations, which hold useful information, but for visualization purpose I need to create a subgraph without these intermediary nodes.

Example :

```
[A:Person] <--AFFILIATE-- [B:Affiliation] --COMPANY--> [C:Org]
```

And I want to produce a subgraph like this :

```
[A:Person] --AFFILIATED_TO--> [C:Org]
```

Is there any simple way to get that with Gremlin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your best option might be to use [subgraph()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) step as you normally might to extract the edge-induced subgraph and then execute some Gremlin on that subgraph to introduce the visualization edges and remove the stuff you don't want.

I can demonstrate with the modern toy graph packaged with TinkerPop:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> sg = g.V().outE('created').subgraph('sg').cap('sg').next() // subgraph creation
==>tinkergraph[vertices:5 edges:4]
gremlin> g = sg.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:5 edges:4], standard]
gremlin> g.V().as('a').                                     // add special subgraph edge
......1>   out('created').as('software').
......2>   in('created').where(neq('a')).
......3>   addE('co-developer').from('a').
......4>     property('project',select('software').by('name')) 
==>e[0][1-co-developer->4]
==>e[1][1-co-developer->6]
==>e[2][4-co-developer->1]
==>e[3][4-co-developer->6]
==>e[4][6-co-developer->1]
==>e[5][6-co-developer->4]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('software').drop() //remove junk from subgraph
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[0][1-co-developer->4]
==>e[1][1-co-developer->6]
==>e[2][4-co-developer->1]
==>e[3][4-co-developer->6]
==>e[4][6-co-developer->1]
==>e[5][6-co-developer->4]
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').outE('co-developer').valueMap(true)
==>[label:co-developer,project:lop,id:0]
==>[label:co-developer,project:lop,id:1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try. That's a bit less straight forward as I expected, but it surely would work.

Comment: I can't think of a better way with the way things currently work, but it would be neat if there were a more straightforward way. I think that this is a common use case. I'll think on it some more.

Comment: It could be great to declare "aliases" on edge patterns and to be able to map a subgraph on it.

Comment: Maybe this is related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-881

Comment: Yes, this feature would allow to implement "inference like" rules, the same way OWL reasoners do. It could be very helpful.